# PHP Server - CLI has stopped working

Tags: php, wamp, laravel

I ve just updated Wamp to PHP 5.4.3 from 5.3.8. Server runned from Wamp is running correctly but if I want to try run PHP new feature and server is Off -

`php artisan serve` 
in laravel4 or

`php -S localhost:8888` from command Line I recieve CLI Has stopped working in Windows 7.

Do you have some suggestions ?

System event error log:

```
Faulting application name: php.exe, version: 5.4.3.0, time stamp: 0x4fb15e42 
Faulting module name: php5ts.dll, version: 5.4.3.0, time stamp: 0x4fb15f2c 
Exception code: 0xc0000005 
Fault offset: 0x0000000000119940 
Faulting process id: 0x6e4 
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce524019a8c721 
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe 
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php5ts.dll
```

Comment: Try looking in events log, maybe there are some error messages there (right-click on my computer, manage, logs and events, applications or something like that).

Comment: Faulting application name: php.exe, version: 5.4.3.0, time stamp: 0x4fb15e42
Faulting module name: php5ts.dll, version: 5.4.3.0, time stamp: 0x4fb15f2c
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000119940
Faulting process id: 0x6e4
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce524019a8c721
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php5ts.dll

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have installed WAMP into Program files, some bits of Apache and PHP dont like having spaces in folder names. Remember this all got ported to Windows from a unix originals and unix does not like spaces in directory names.

Try re-installing into c:\wamp