# php cli has stopped working

Tags: php, powershell

I have a fresh windows 8 installation:

Downloaded php-(5.6.11 zip) from this [this page](http://windows.php.net/download/):
Unzipped it to "C:\Users\patrick\php".

Don't know if this is important:
*Copied and renamed php.ini-development to php.ini.

Changed display_errors from off to on.*

Added "C:\Users\patrick\php" to my Environment Variable Path.
Started Windows PowerShell.
Typed in "php -S localhost:8000"
"CLI has stopped working" pops up with no more information.

(OBS: Doesn't matter what I type in after "php", same message pops up)

Similar but not exactly the same Stack Overflow questions:
[PHP 5.3.0 as distributed in a xampp 1.7.2 .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671995/php-cli-has-stopped-working)
Solved by updating his PHP version bundled with xampp. Since I don't run my php with xampp yet I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

[updated Wamp to PHP 5.4.3 from 5.3.8.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590088/php-server-cli-has-stopped-working)
Not solved but suggested he should not have installed WAMP into Program files, some bits of Apache and PHP dont like having spaces in folder names. This shouldn't be an issue with "C:\Users\patrick\php" right?

There are a few other php-related "CLI has stopped working" problems, but all of the ones I found only occurred in specific events, such as "When I use this function..." etc.

---

Using Process Monitor, I've found that the `php.exe` process keeps looking for a DLL file in all my Path folders:

[image]

Comment: Are you running PowerShell as an Administrator? You need admin privileges to bind on localhost:8000

Comment: I wasn't running it as Administrator but the problem seems to persist regardless. It also seems as if any php-command produces the same issue ("php", "php -h", "-php -a", etc.)

Comment: Interesting. You might want to fire up [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) and see what `php.exe` is actually trying to do when it dies

Comment: Do you have any tip on how to do that (with procmon)? I downloaded it, fired it up and got overwhelmed of information i.e. "Showing 58.000 events of 156.000 events (32%)". Tried to apply a filter and tried [ path includes "php" -> include ] but when I activated the filter I got nothing (while trying to run php from powershell at the same time).  
  
EDIT: Changed the filter to "Process name is php.exe" and got a bunch of stuff, I'll get back to you soon with a screen-shot or some info.

Comment: Here's what happens in procmon:
http://s23.postimg.org/vlpennxx5/screenshot_for_stackoverflow.png
EDIT: It looks like it's going through my Environment Variable Path looking for some DLL-file (the long list of FILE NOT FOUND is going through every folder in my path, i.e. VLC and Python and stuff.

Comment: As you can see, it's looking for `MSVCR110.dll` - that's the MS Visual C++ Runtime 11.0. Download the VS2012 (v. 11.0) C++ redistributable package and install it on your machine. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: You know what, that fixed it! Everything seems to work now but wow I would not have come to that conclusion myself. Don't know if I can mark a comment as a solution here?

Comment: Added a proper answer instead :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we've established, the `php.exe` executable tries to locate a library called `MSVCR110.dll` on startup.

`MSVCR110` stands for **M**icro**s**oft  **V**isual **C**++ **R**untime **11**.**0**.

This runtime library is part of the Visual C++ Redistributable packages that comes with Visual Studio, and that you can download and install on it's own from Microsoft - they even maintain a list of download links in [KB2977003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003#bookmark-vs2012).

You'll want the [Visual Studio 2012 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) (corresponds to VC++ version 11.0).

Once installed, it'll also update the path env variable, and `php.exe` should then be able to locate it on startup